# SQL query based on combobox selection

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am creating a database application and I'm having difficulty implementing a query. I have a query which populates a combobox with customer's bank accounts this is the code for the query:

```
private void ShowAccounts()
            {
                string sql = "SELECT account.custid, product.name FROM account INNER JOIN product ON account.prodid = product.prodid WHERE account.custid = @AccountID";
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionScring))
                {
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", customerData.CustomerID);
                    connection.Open();

                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            comboAccounts.Items.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
                        }


                    }
                }
```

This works the way I need it to but based on the account selection I need to display the account balance and I'm wondering how to go about writing that query. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: My question is, based on the query above how would I go about writing another query that gets the balance of the selected account?

Comment: Do you know what the balance column is called?

Comment: The balance is called balance. Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is to return the balance from the select account and store that balance inside a label

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are trying to do? I am guessing on your column and table names so you will need to modify the sql statement if I got it wrong.

```
    private string Get_Balance(string AccountNumber)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT balance FROM account WHERE custid = @AccountID";
        string balance = "";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionScring))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID", AccountNumber);
            connection.Open();

            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    balance = reader["balance"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return (balance);
    }
```

Use the SelectedIndexChanged event of your combo box to call the above code. You will need to add the event handler to the combo box (just double click it on the form and VS will do it for you).

```
    private void comboAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboAccounts.Text != "")
        {
            balanceLabel.text = Get_Balance(comboAccounts.text); //Or whatever you named the label you want your balance to to into.
        }
    }
```

After you populate your combo box with your code, whenever the combo box is dropped down and changed it will pass the text of whatever is in the combo box to Get_Balance which will return a string that will be placed in the label.